# Problema para enviar correo automático de Outlook desde R, con Librería emayili

Tags: r, outlook

Espero me puedan ayudar, hace un tiempo estoy ejecutando un código de R con la librería emayili para enviar correos de Outlook automáticamente cuando ejecuto el código, sin embargo, hace algunas semanas me aparece este error al ejecutar el código de envío, he buscado para tratar de solucionarlo, pero no he encontrado nada. Por favor si me pudieran ayudar, se los  agradecería demasiado.

Este es el código:

```
library(emayili)

smtp <- emayili::server(host = "smtp.office365.com",         
                        port = 587,  
                        username = "xxxx@xxx.cl", 
                        password = "xxxxxxxxx")

email <- emayili::envelope(from = "ttttt@tttt.cl",
                           to = c('uuuuu@uuuu.cl'),
                           subject = paste0('Asunto Correo')) %>%
  html(paste("<p>Buenos días,</p>
  <p>Adjunto archivo Bla bla </p>
  <p>Saludos!</p>", sep = "")) %>% 
  attachment(paste0("Adjunto_archivo_correo.xlsx"))

smtp(email, verbose = FALSE)
```

Este es el error que genera,

```
Error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

(Por lo que entiendo indica que se realizaron 5 intentos y fallaron)

Ejecuto rlang::last_trace() y me aparece lo siguiente:

```
<error/purrr_error_rate_excess>
Error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts.
---
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-emayili (local) smtp(email, verbose = FALSE)
 2.   \-purrr (local) send_mail(...) at emayili/R/server.R:190:5
 3.     \-purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.
```

Luego ejecuto esto rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) y me aparece lo siguiente:

```
<error/purrr_error_rate_excess>
Error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts.
---
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-emayili (local) smtp(email, verbose = FALSE)
 2.   \-purrr (local) send_mail(...) at emayili/R/server.R:190:5
 3.     \-purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
 4.       \-purrr:::stop_rate_excess(rate)
 5.         \-cli::cli_abort(...)
 6.           \-rlang::abort(...)
```

Muchas gracias, cualquier aporte será bien recibido.